# Exist $\alpha < \infty$, $\beta > 0$ such that $\mathbb{P}\{T_\lambda > t\} \le \alpha e^{-\beta t}?$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion. Suppose $\lambda > 0$ and let$$T_\lambda = \min\{t : |B_t| = \lambda\}.$$Do there exist $\alpha < \infty$ and $\beta > 0$ (which may depend on $\lambda$) such that for all $t$, we have$$\mathbb{P}\{T_\lambda > t\} \le \alpha e^{-\beta t}?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using that $$M_t := \exp(i \xi B_t + \frac{t}{2} \xi^2)$$ is a martingale, one can show that for any $\lambda>0$ there exists $\beta>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}e^{\beta T_{\lambda}}<\infty.$$ By Markov's inequality, this implies in particular that

$$\mathbb{P}(T_{\lambda} \geq t) \leq e^{-\beta t} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(e^{\beta T_{\lambda}})}_{\alpha}.$$

(See e.g. *René Schilling, Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Problem 5.17(i) for a proof.)

**Remark:** As @zhoraster pointed out, one can calculate $\mathbb{E}e^{\beta T_{\lambda}}$ explicitly and find that the expectation is finite for any $\beta \in (0,\frac{\pi^2}{8\lambda})$.

Comment: In fact, by considering this martingale, $E[e^{\beta T_\lambda}] = (\cos\sqrt{2\beta\lambda})^{-1}$, so any $\beta \in(0,\frac{\pi^2}{8\lambda})$ will do.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact, seems that $P(T_\lambda>t) \sim e^{-\lambda^* t}$ with $\lambda^* = \pi^2/8$.

Comment: No problem. With my mobile app on iPod touch this happens sometimes.  Don't know whether the asymptotics is true and/or written anywhere (I know only about $P(T_\lambda>t) \asymp e^{-\lambda^* t}$).