# Exercise 8.12 Introduction to stochastic processes Gregory Lawler

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ be a standard Brownian motion starting at 0 and let

$T=min \{t:|X_t|=1\}$ and $\hat{T}=min \{t:X_t=1\}$
(a) Show that there exist positive constants $c$, $\beta$ such that for all $t>0$,
$$P(T>t)\leq ce^{-\beta t}$$
conclude that $E(T)\leq \infty$
use the reflection principle to fine the density of $\hat{T}$, and show that $E(\hat{T})=\infty$
Please help me to start to solve this problem.

Comment: Exercise 8.12 Introduction to stochastic processes Lawler

Comment: Are you sure it is $P(T>t) \le ce^{-\beta}$, not $P(T>t) \le ct^{-\beta}$?

Comment: @Jay.H I corrected it. thank you

Comment: For the first part of your problem see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441423/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, let

$ X_t^* = \max_{s\in [0\ t]}X_s$

note that:

$P(\hat T \le t) = P(X_t^*\ge 1)$

and also, by reflection principle, you can show that the pdf of $X_t^*$ is twice the pdf of $X_t$, but defined on $[0\ \infty)$ only.

Put these together, you get the cdf of $\hat T$

$P(\hat T \le t) = 2(1- \phi(1/{\sqrt{t}}))$

where $\phi$ is the cdf of standard normal r.v., and by integration by parts, you can prove that $E(\hat T)=\infty$.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  By reflection principle we have $P(\hat T \le t) = 2 P(X_t \geq 1)=2 (1-\phi(1))$ , but you have written $2(1- \phi(1/{\sqrt{t}}))$ why?

Comment: Because $X_t$ is not standard normal, its variance is t, not 1.